# Retroift coroutines livedata called only first time

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, kotlin-coroutines

I'm just new with kotlin coroutines. I just created new project for testing livedata but i cant observe data changes. I didn't understand the concept of livedata. When it'll be trigger? Because when i observe ROOM database(Not the coroutines way. i used the MutableLiveData) it was working very well. Observer was always triggered whenever data changed.

I just wanted to clean and modern code. My expectations: when I click btnLogin button (when user login with another account or you can say when data changes) livedata must trigger.

Here is my example:

Retrofit interface:

```
interface RetroMainClient {

    @POST("login.php")
    suspend fun login(@Body model: UserLoginModel): Response<UserLoginModel>

    companion object {
        val getApi: RetroMainClient by lazy {
            Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://example.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().create())).build()
                .create(RetroMainClient::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

My repository:

```
class Repository {
    suspend fun getLoginApi(model: UserLoginModel) = RetroMainClient.getApi.login(model)
}
```

My viewModel:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    fun login(model: UserLoginModel) = liveData(IO) {
        try {
            emit(Repository().getLoginApi(model))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("exception", "${e.message}")
        }
    }
}
```

and my MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        var model = UserLoginModel("user1", "123456")

        viewModel.login(model).observe(this, Observer {

            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                btnLogin.text = it.body()?.username
            }

        })

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener {
            model = UserLoginModel("user2", "123456")

            CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
                try {
                    Repository().getLoginApi(model)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.e("exception:", "${e.message}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `viewModel.login()` method you create a new instance of `LiveData` class. In order to execute corresponding block in `viewModel.login()` after every click on `btnLogin` button you need call `LiveData.observe()` method for every `viewModel.login()` call.

In `MainActivity`'s `onCreate` method:

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener {
    model = UserLoginModel("user2", "123456")
    viewModel.login(model).observe(this, Observer { data ->
        if (it.isSuccessful) {
            btnLogin.text = data.body()?.username
        }
    })
}
```

**ANOTHER APPROACH**:

is to launch a **coroutine** in `MainViewModel` class and update `LiveData` field manually:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val loginResponse: LiveData<Response<UserLoginModel>> = MutableLiveData<Response<UserLoginModel>>()

    fun login(model: UserLoginModel) = viewModelScope.launch(IO) {
        try {
            (loginResponse as MutableLiveData).postValue(Repository().getLoginApi(model))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("exception", "${e.message}")
        }
    }
}


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        var model = UserLoginModel("user1", "123456")

        viewModel.loginResponse.observe(this, Observer {

            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                btnLogin.text = it.body()?.username
            }

        })

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener {
            model = UserLoginModel("user2", "123456")

            viewModel.login(model)
        }
    }
}
```

To use `viewModelScope` in `MainViewModel` class add dependency to build.gradle file:

> final LIFECYCLE_VERSION = "2.2.0-rc03" // add most recent version
>
> api "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$LIFECYCLE_VERSION"

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. I researched for hours and i knew i'm creating new instance every time i click the button. But i didn't figure out how to avoid it. Thank you so much.

Comment: You saved my life :)